# How to open a file from db in php

Tags: php, mysql

I created a profile page to view members info's one of the information is his/her cv. I Could manage viewing a window that have an open or download options BUT I have two problems:

1- in Chrome open option dose not appear I have download option only.

2- I cant open nor download the cv in both chrome and Firefox, the file name appear with the server name in the open or save window.

Here is my code:
PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['cv'])) 
 {
   $id = $_GET['cv'];

   $query = "SELECT `fileName`, `fileType`, `fileSize`, `fileContent` FROM `boardteam` WHERE `nationalID` = '$id'";

    $r = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

    list($fname, $ftype, $fsize, $fcontent) = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fname");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fsize));
    ob_clean();
    flush(); 
    readfile($fname);
    exit;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href='browseMember.php?cv=<?php echo $member_id?>'>
<?php 
     $q = "SELECT `fileName`, `fileType`, `fileSize`, `fileContent` FROM `boardteam` WHERE `nationalID` = '$member_id'";

     $r = mysql_query($q) or die('Error, query failed');

     list($fname, $ftype, $fsize, $fcontent) = mysql_fetch_array($r);
     if ($fname)
       {
         echo "click here to open member CV";
       }
?>
</a>
```

UPDATE:

Lets assume cv file type is docx, If it works I will switch to case doc and pdf and change content type.

Comment: try this


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346117/how-can-i-view-open-a-word-document-in-my-browser-using-with-php-or-html

Comment: What actually is your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251956/is-there-a-pdf-parser-for-php

Comment: @Testing I want to open the cv but my code open a download window :(

Comment: Would you dont mind posting your complete code? Lets fix it now. Post your complete code with proper flow how and where code flow is going in site.

Comment: Let me understand: are you trying to open IN A BROWSER a word document?

Comment: @STTLCU No not in the BROWSER I want to view CV in Microsoft word not downloading it

Comment: You want to see a remote file with a local program without downloading it, right? Good luck.

Comment: @STTLCU No OMG I have an issue in writing a clear question :") ,, I want to enable users of opening or downloading their CVs of doc format witch is stored in db not in file system .. sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: oh, now that makes more sense. well, that's outside of your control. It relies on the user's browser preference. You can't auto-open a file unless the user has already decided to automatically do so. Standard behaviour is prompt-download-action where action can either be save or open file.

Comment: @STTLCU alright I wanna follow the standers but how ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your content type setting. Your browser doesn't know which application to open the document with when it is binary. Try changing the content type with a more descriptive content type that lets the browser select the appropriate application. For example for PDF it would be `application/x-pdf`. Refer the [MIME Media type directory](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/) for others.

Comment: I change it to application/msword for doc file But still it open a downloading window :(

Comment: Is it a doc or a docx? docx files are gzip files. Try with a PDF first to see if it works.

Comment: I allow doc, docx and pdf, None is working as I want even now I tried the pdf mime content type in browsing member profile who's CV is in pdf format it still give me a window to select where to download that pdf :(

Comment: I could not open any version both pdf and docx it says that its corrupted and the file name that appears in the window is the server name, Could you guess the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

Since, you only want to open it in browser so, it should work for you.

Please replace `YOUR_DIRECOTRY_WHERE_FILE_IS_PRESENT_PHYSICALY` with your directory name where you document files are physically present.

Your **browseMember.php** code will be like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['cv'])) 
 {
    $id = $_GET['cv'];

    $query = "SELECT `fileName`, `fileType`, `fileSize`, `fileContent` FROM `boardteam` WHERE `nationalID` = '$id'";

    $r = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

    while ($rowDoc = mysql_fetch_array($r)){ ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div><a href="YOUR_DIRECOTRY_WHERE_FILE_IS_PRESENT_PHYSICALY/<?=$rowDoc['fileName']; ?>" target="_blank" class="text_2" style="text-decoration:none;" ><strong><? echo($row_pdf['fileName']);?></strong></a></div>
    </div>
<?php
echo "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Even though I added case "docx": $ctype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; break; It still ask where to download :"(

Comment: See edited answer. You should use your code this way.

Comment: I store CVs in db not in system files !

Comment: Also I want to enable (open CV and download) both options to the users.

Comment: But CVs should be somewhere physically present or not? :)

Comment: Means? Open in browser and then download in browser? 2 processes?

Comment: OK I will explain more clearly : When User open his/her profile, he/she can click on "open my Cv link" then my site will open a window asking the user to select open or download ,, just link those pictuers in [this question]:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515046/force-file-download-pdf-open-with-box-says-its-a-firefox-document)